# Cities-In-Motion-2 rule-set usage

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

- Can i apply a rule-set to campaign mode in Cities-In-Motion-2? I created a new one and want to apply it. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2):

What you would like to accomplish is not possible. Rule-sets are for sandbox mode only, meaning it can't be applied to campaigns. For source and further infos see: https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/rulesets-how-to-use.717453/